# XSLT: How to extract xml content from xslt variable

Tags: xml, xslt, substring, cdata

Input XML:

```
<Resp>
      <Data><![CDATA[QREMLGBU <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?><Envelope><Headers><Headers><Body><Response>
;
;;
;;;
</Response></Body></Envelope>
</Data>
</Resp>
```

I would like to get the xml from element  into a variable and extract the element from this variable(using XPATH).
(first 49 characters only are fixed,rest can change).

```
<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:variable name="abc">
      <xsl:value-of select="substring(/Resp/Data,49)"/>
    </xsl:variable>
 </xsl:template>
```

I am able to get the value into variable abc as

```
<Envelope><Headers><Headers><Body><Response></Response></Body></Envelope>
```

BUT, not able to use that variable further as XML element.

```
Example: 
<xsl:copy-of select="$abc/Envelope/Body/Response"/>
```

Could any one help me in getting the output as below.

```
<Response>
;
;;
;;;
</Response>
```

Answer (score 3):

Because this is nested XML in a CDATA section, the XML parser treats it as a single text node (the CDATA effectively says "ignore anything in here that looks like markup, treat it as text."). So you need to extract the text as a string and then pass it to another parser to turn it into a tree of nodes. There's no standard way of doing that until XSLT/XPath 3.0, but some processors have extensions. With Saxon-PE or higher you can use the XPath 3.0 function `parse-xml()`.